# Entity Framework removendo entitdades que tem fk

Tags: entity-framework-6

Tenho no meu repository, meu método de deletar

```
public virtual void Deletar(int Id)
{
  var entity = _dbSet.Find(Id);
  _dbSet.Remove(entity);
}
```

O problema é que ele está deletando mesmo se está com FK em outra tabela, e eu não quero que ele delete, o que está errado?

Comment: Você tem que criar contraints de banco de dados. Não há magica. Ou então validar via aplicação, que também não é simples.

Comment: Fernando, ao gerar o banco (code first) já é gerado com FK

Comment: Qual banco de dados você utiliza?

Comment: Sql Server 2012

Comment: Era para gerar uma exceção no banco de dados, se há a constraint corretamente.

Comment: Fernando, achei o erro já, estava numa configuração do Entity Framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por padrão,o entity framework vem com o Cascade habilitado, então desabilitei ele e ele foi na minha exception

```
  modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
```